# libgdx button up down no effect

Tags: button, libgdx, kotlin

```
val playTexture = assetManager?.get(A.image.gamePlayBtn, Texture::class.java)

val skin: Skin = Skin()
skin.add("up", TextureRegion(playTexture, 0, 0, 296, 96))
skin.add("down", TextureRegion(playTexture, 0, 96, 296, 96))

val playButton: ImageTextButton = ImageTextButton("PLAY THE GAME", with(ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle()) {
    up = skin.getDrawable("up")
    down = skin.getDrawable("down")
    font = BitmapFont()
    font.data.setScale(3f)
    font.color = Color.ORANGE
    this
})
```

OnClick events work ok, but there is no button background change for onClicked state(down). Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I tested your code, Everything working fine as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code, that's working fine. Added complete text code :

```
class Main : ApplicationAdapter(){

   internal lateinit var stage: Stage

   override fun create() {

    stage= Stage()
    stage.setDebugAll(true)
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)

    var skin= Skin()
    var tex1 =Texture("badlogic.jpg")
    skin.add("up", TextureRegion(tex1, 0, 0, 100, 50))
    skin.add("down", TextureRegion(tex1, 0, 96, 100, 50))

    var playButton: ImageTextButton = ImageTextButton("Play The Game", with(ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle()){

        up = skin.getDrawable("up")
        down = skin.getDrawable("down")
        font = BitmapFont()
        font.data.setScale(3f)
        font.color = Color.ORANGE
        this
    });

    playButton.setPosition(0F,100F)
    playButton.addListener(object : ClickListener(){

        override fun clicked(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float) {
            print("clicked")
            super.clicked(event, x, y)
        }
    })

    stage.addActor(playButton)
  }

  override fun render() {

      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

      stage.draw()
      stage.act()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your button.
There is updateImage() function, but its protected so u have to do it using Stage.

So here is what u do:

1. Create stage.
2. Add your button to stage.
3. Call stage.draw() in render function.

   ```
   ...
   Stage stage = new Stage();
   //create button
   stage.addActor(playButton);
   ...


   @Override
   public void render() {      
       stage.draw();
   }
   ```